# How to effectively deal with quantization error in Matlab so that it meets the amplitude specification

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

I am trying to design a FIR filter in Matlab that can be used to meet certain amplitude specification. The problem is that the gain calculated after calculating the coefficient using firpm function and the gain calculated with quantised coefficients are not the same. Please note that the order of the filter is calculated correctly.

Is there any way to keep both the gains same?

Comment: In general, the quantized gain can not be made exactly the same for an arbitrary FIR design.  The size of the minimum difference possible will depend on the gain, the quantization step size, and order of the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can, by trial and error, add noise filtered random dithering before quantization until the difference in total gain is minimized.